# Artifactory: Download exploded archive

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I cannot help thinking I am missing the point.

I have a jenkins system that is to store builds in artifactory pro, I would like to end up able to compare builds on the artifactory server and download a set of files as a zip file.

The output of my build is a few thousand files in a folder structure.

As I understand it, artifactory uses a de-duplicating file system so the efficient way to do it is to upload each file individually as only a few change each build.

When I do this, it takes 20 mins but the result on the server is good, I can compare builds and see the changes, however I cannot download the whole release, I need to click on each file and do them one by one.

If I upload a zip file, it is quicker and I can download it, but I loose the ability to see the files inside and presumably this will eat up disk space as there can be no de-duplication.

Ah - the explode option, this unpacks the zip file on the artifactory server, brilliant, except if I diff builds it just shows me the original archive and says, it changed, yet I still have to download every file individually.

Has any one cracked this thing, I want fast upload, diff files (with efficient storage) and single click download?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. Do you want to download only the diffs or the entire build files?

Comment: I would like to download all the files in a single zip file.

Answer (score 3):

To download files in a "single click" you can either:

- Use the [REST API to download a folder](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) as a compressed file
- Use the [JFrog CLI to download files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) in a single command using file specs.

HTH,
Yinon

Comment: I was hoping more for something users can do if I point them at the webserver, but I see there is a setting to enable folder download.

If that is set might they get a download option in the UI? (easier to ask here than get the admins to change something :) )